# What are "stack number" and "slice number" in GVRSceneobject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, 360-degrees, gear-vr

I was running some gvrf [sample applications](https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos). I was going through the code and I found out that the GVRSceneobject has some properties called "stack number" and "slice number".

- For GVRCylinderSceneObject default values are 2 and 36 respectively.
- For GVRSphereSceneObject default values are 18 and 36 respectively.

Could somebody explain me what do the "stack number" and "slice number" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with Gear VR, but stacks and slices are common terms in Virtual Reality, so I try to help.

Basically, the `slices`' value is the number of subdivisions around the X axis. Similarly, the `stacks`' value is the number of subdivisions around the Y axis (X and Y axis are used in OpenGL's definitions, I hope that they correspond to Gear VR as well).

So, you can imagine *slices* and *stacks* as *latitude* and *longitude*.

This image (from [here](http://engineerportal.blogspot.it/2012/08/opengl-quadrics-material-7_25.html)) represents a sphere with different values for slices and stacks. It should clarify the concept (higher values imply more subdivisions):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the `GVRCylinderSceneObject` [source code](https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/blob/master/GVRf/Framework/framework/src/main/java/org/gearvrf/scene_objects/GVRCylinderSceneObject.java), below is the definition of `StackNumber` and `SliceNumber` properties.

*[`GVRCylinderSceneObject`](https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/blob/master/GVRf/Framework/framework/src/main/java/org/gearvrf/scene_objects/GVRCylinderSceneObject.java) class*:

- `StackNumber` is the number of stacks in cylinder body (default 10)
- `SliceNumber` is the number of slices in cylinder caps (default 36).

You can find the definition of `StackNumber` and `SliceNumber` properties for the `GVRSphereSceneObject` class [here](https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/blob/master/GVRf/Framework/framework/src/main/java/org/gearvrf/scene_objects/GVRSphereSceneObject.java).

*[`GVRSphereSceneObject`](https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/blob/master/GVRf/Framework/framework/src/main/java/org/gearvrf/scene_objects/GVRSphereSceneObject.java) class:*

- `StackNumber` is the number of stacks for the sphere. It should be equal or greater than 3.
- `SliceNumber` is the number of slices for the sphere. It should be equal or greater than 4.

These variables are used when constructing a sphere or cylinder to provide how many `stack` and `slice` should be in the newly constructed Mesh. Both `GVRCylinderSceneObject` and `GVRSphereSceneObject` 
class have a constructor that creates new cylinder or sphere and those two variables are used to determine their stack and slice values. You can read more about stack  and slice [here](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1904).